# app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() doesn't seem to be working on ASP .NET Core on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, asp.net, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

Very simple ASP .NET core application so far. I've turned on the developer exception page as follows

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

I've deployed it on windows as a portable app and i'm able to see the errors on the developer page (awesome page by the way) when a specific web API request fails with an exception.

I publish the same app to Ubuntu as a self-contained app and I don't get the developer error page to show up (though the seems to run fine - i've hard coded an error just to test the developer page itself).

Answer (score 3):

By default on macOS and Linux ASP.NET Core's Hosting environment is Production.

On Ubuntu you can start the application and set the Hosting environment from command line using

`> dotnet run --environment=Development`

For macOS:

`$ ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development dotnet run`

If you are using Visual Studio Code, in launch.json there's the following setting for each configuration:

`"env": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }`

Comment: Very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Developer Exception Page is for use when the environment is Development.

See https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/working-with-environments-and-launch-settings-in-asp-net-core/

The act of publishing the app to Ubuntu is setting the environment to Production.

Comment: I think you are right in that it is setting the environment variable to production. However, I'm not checking for environment variable like many of the examples do. I'm asking it to UseDeveloperExceptionPage regardless. To prove the point, do you have any idea how i can set the environment to Development on the Ubuntu deployment. That way if it still doesn't work, then we know the environment variable isn't the problem.

Comment: In your publish settings ensure your Configuration is Debug instead of Release. There should be a file appsettings.Development.json included in your published files on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

This is the behavior I found: (ASP.NET Core version 6, on Windows)

- When environment is Development, exception pages are always generated, regardless of whether `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` was called.
- When environment is anything other than Development, exceptions pages are generated only if `UseDeveloperExceptionPage` was called.

Comment: I would seem to be observing the same behavior... and in addition to this, if I instead call `UseExceptionHandler` when running in Development-environment mode it seems to ignore this call and instead only gives me the developer exception page...

Answer (score 1):

Startup.cs is mostly procedural. In your **Startup.cs**

```
 app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

should come before

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapControllers();
     endpoints.MapRazorPages();
 });
```

If you add it after then it won't function.